# eclipse showing error on many correct lines

Tags: eclipse

I was working as usual on Eclipse as usual. But when I closed one project and created another, and out of nowhere the class is showing errors on every line.
ِAnd crashing every time, any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Well, what kind of errors is it showing?

Comment: it won't let me know it crashes whenever I press anything

Comment: Take a look at the Error View after the restart, maybe it carries entries from before the crash. And besides - you can just hover over the error markers to see what they are complaining about, without having to press anything.

Comment: You have exactly two issues here and should be two questions asked.

Comment: To investigate the crash there should be javacore file generated in Eclipse install directory. It should contain one line containing the cause of the crash. Please put it here or provide entire javacore file.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu now Eclipse is just crashing, without even doing anything, and won't let me check the error view

Comment: @kazik1616 do you have any idea where I can find the file exactly, I have the android adt-bundle where there's no actual install

Comment: But there surely is a place where an eclipse.exe is hanging around? Look there for something looking like a crashdump (root folder or configuration subfolder).

Comment: And also try to start your eclipse with the -clean argument.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu How can I start eclipse with command line? I'm on Windows

Comment: and I really couldn't any such file as crashdump or so?

Comment: @SamIbraheem You can add the argument to the link you are using right now to start Eclipse. Just add  -clean to the end of the text in the "Target" field of the link's property page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is something wrong with your imports or your package name and class name is not matching the code.

Comment: but why is Eclipse itself crashing? And I didn't even write one line in the new project?

Comment: @SamIbraheem  Are you getting an error or is it just shutting itself down?

Comment: Besides the errors on every line? None, nothing in the error view